# Are labels of Jenkins build slaves checked in a case sensitive manner for job scripts?

Tags: jenkins, label

When i have two build clients, where one has a label of "Windows" (1st char is capitalized) and the other has a label of "windows" (all lower case), will i either need to write a job label formula of "(Windows || windows)" (assumed the case of the label is respected) or is either "Windows" or "windows" (assumed the comparison is case-insensitive) sufficient to freely run the job on any of both machines, whichever is first or free?

I have to ask, because i felt like i was unable to determine from docs in what fashion this is set up. (Some docs even indicate that some other check-operations are configurable in respect to case'ness.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Node labels are **case sensitive** in jenkins. So, When you write (Windows || windows) as a target node, jenkins will first try to run the job on the agent with label "Windows" in case if that agent doesn't respond then it will try to run the same job on the second agent with label "windows". If you want to run a job freely on any of the available agents then there are two way to accomplish that

1. Define the RegEx for those agents with OR (||) symbol (for example "Windows || windows"), which you already have.
2. Have the same label name on both agents (for example "windows") and have your job run with label "windows". It will run in a little different manner. In this case when you run that job with target label "windows", jenkins will send the request to both nodes but jenkins will run the job on the agent which will respond first.